# How should I truncate dynamic string in the middle using JS or CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

How should I truncate **dynamic string** in the middle using JS or CSS?

**Example dynamic string:-**

```
<div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>
```

**Expected string:-**

```
Test > run > test > run > ... run > run > test > run
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think he wants to split this and keep the words as they are. Imo this is not the same as your duplicate. What do you think, @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The function in the top answer of the duplicate is exactly what the OP needs. See: http://jsfiddle.net/2eUYN/70/. If you don't want to update the DOM that's fine, but the logic of the function is the solution.

Comment: I mean, that this should not happen: http://jsfiddle.net/2eUYN/71/ @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with the following regex

```
((?:[^>]+>){4}).+((?:>[^>]+){4})
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/xC3dC8/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```js
$('.selected-option').text(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/((?:[^>]+>){4}).+((?:>[^>]+){4})/, '$1 ... $2')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>
```

---

---

If you don't want the `>` after `...` then  use the following regex

```
((?:[^>]+>){4}).+>([^>]+(?:>[^>]+){3})
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/xC3dC8/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```js
$('.selected-option').text(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/((?:[^>]+>){4}).+>([^>]+(?:>[^>]+){3})/, '$1 ... $2')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selected-option">Test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > test > run > run > test > run</div>
```

Comment: It resolved my problem. Thanks for your Answer.

Comment: @Gsk : glad to help you :)